# Implementação de CRUD genérico

Tags: c#, sql, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, crud

Tenho a seguinte classe `CRUD` que é genérica:

```
public abstract class CRUD
{
    protected string tabela = null;
    protected object classe = null;

    public CRUD() {}

    public virtual void insert() { //código }
    public virtual void select() { //código }
}
```

Criei outra classe quer herda da classe `CRUD`:

```
public abstract class PessoaCRUD : CRUD
{
   public PessoaCRUD()
   {
       tabela = "TBUsuarios";
       classe = this;    
   }

   //sobrescrita do metódo da classe pai
   public void insert() { //código }
}
```

E Tenho minha classe Pessoa que herda de PessoaCRUD:

```
public class Pessoa : PessoaCRUD
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
}
```

E quando preciso usar a classe pessoa ficara algo assim:

```
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();

pessoa.Nome = "Julia";
pessoa.Idade = 23;
pessoa.Insert();
```

A princípio está funcionando, mas fiquei com dúvida, poderia fazer a classe `Pessoa` herda da classe `CRUD`, porém caso algum método necessite de sobrescrita ele teria quer ser implementado na classe `Pessoa`, e não querendo poluir a classe `Pessoa` com métodos relacionados ao `CRUD` criei a classe `PessoaCRUD`.

Está correto implementar assim? caso contrário qual seria uma abordagem melhor, levando em consideração padrões de projeto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Está correto implementar assim?

Não. A abordagem é incorreta para manipulação de coleções, pois torna o procedimento de manipulação de registros complexo e ruim em termos de desempenho.

Você está definindo uma classe que guarda dados e ao mesmo tempo se autogerencia. Pro caso de 1000 registros, por exemplo, você teria que chamar `insert` 1000 vezes, sendo uma para cada objeto. O maior problema é o gasto com memória, replicando 1000 vezes objetos com a mesma lógica de negócio.

## Caso contrário qual seria uma abordagem melhor, levando em consideração padrões de projeto?

Este é o caso clássico da implementação de um repositório, mas há algumas observações a se fazer.

### 1. Separe a classe de dados da classe de manipulação de registros.

A classe `CRUD` está correta do ponto de vista de um repositório, exceto pela propriedade `classe`, que não é útil nem necessária para a sua implementação.

O que é interessante fazer é usar tipo genérico para separar a classe de representação de dados da classe que faz as operações em banco (vulgo repositório):

```
public abstract class CRUD<T>
    where T: IEntidade
{
    protected string tabela = null;
    protected object classe = null;

    public CRUD() {}

    public virtual void insert(T objeto) { //código }
    public virtual void select(int id) { //código }
    ...
}
```

### 2. Utilize classes genéricas para definir seu repositório

Já `PessoaCRUD` não precisa ser `abstract`:

```
public class PessoaCRUD<Pessoa> : CRUD<Pessoa>
{
   public PessoaCRUD()
   {
       tabela = "TBUsuarios";
   }

   //sobrescrita do metódo da classe pai
   public override void insert(Pessoa objeto) { //código }
}
```

`Pessoa` deve apenas representar dados:

```
public class Pessoa : IEntidade
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
}
```

### 3. Restrinja suas classes de dados por interfaces

Por fim, defina a interface `IEntidade` para definir o formato das classes de representação de dados:

```
public interface IEntidade 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Essa implementação está acoplando as suas regras de negócio que entendo ficariam na classe Pessoa com o código acesso ao banco de dados.
É interessante mesmo separar as coisas como você chegou a fazer mas a herança separa as coisas quanto a leitura do código mas logicamente não, por este motivo o indicado é usar composição ao invés de herança.
Neste caso você ainda teria as mesmas classes, mas a classe Pessoa seria passada como parametro para a PessoaCRUD ou a PessoaCRUD poderia ser injetada na classe pessoa.
Não encontrei links explicando a famosa regra "Prefira composição ao invés de Herança" com C#, mas esse [link aq é bacana](http://blog.caelum.com.br/como-nao-aprender-orientacao-a-objetos-heranca/)!

Comment: vou dar uma olhada...

Answer (score 1):

A classe pessoa, representa uma Pessoa e um "crud" representa seu repositório de pessoas, eles não deveria ter uma dependência baseada em herança pois representam objetos distintos.

Um representa uma pessoa do mundo real e o outro representa o lugar onde você guarda informações. Você está concentrando os detalhes do repositorio de pessoas junto a classe pessoa. Uma alternativa melhor seria usar classes abstratas ou mesmo generics para os repositorios e herdar um repositorio diferenciado para cada instância de objeto a ser armazenado.

Isso vai reduzir o acoplamento e permitirá um nível de manutenção menor a longo prazo. Um outro problema é que como você usa a classe pessoa para herdar do repositorio, se você está usando arquiteturas em camadas, você acabou de complicar a vida na hora de garantir que as camadas mais altas não acessem os repositorios diretamente.